# Force a service worker caching to fail for testing purposes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, service-worker, web-worker

I'm working with my QA team to try and test some new error handling we added to our service worker when it tries to cache some of our JS bundles and I'm looking for a way to cause either one of the cache methods to fail (`cache.add`, `cache.open`, `cache.match`, etc.)

We'd like to be able to test this without changing any code, so, ideally, I would love to find a way to block cache requests in the same way that you can block HTTP requests (or something similar).

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: In the Chrome console, under the Network tab, there is a checkbox to disable the cache while the console is open. That may help?

Comment: Unfortunately, that seems to only block the HTTP cache and doesn't affect anything manually cached by a web worker :/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out (at least in Chrome)!

In the Chrome console at the top left you can select the context in which the console is running and one of the options is the service worker.

Once you are in there, you can over write the cache functions however you want. For my purposes, I just did `self.caches.open = () => Promise.reject("Error")`.